# bit wise multiplication issue

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, multiplication

I have a programming assignment to take in 2 integers as hex the write a function to multiply then using bit-wise operations. It works for every number combination I can come up with but when I put in 2 of the examples given on the assignment sheet, my answer is close but not exact. I am hoping for some help as to why it is not getting the exact correct answers. My function is posted below and the answer I get vs what I should get are below that. Thanks in advanced for any insight.

```
long unsigned product = 0;
int count = 0;

while(b != 0){
    if((b & 0x01) != 0){
        product = BinaryAdd(product, a); //BinaryAdd simply adds two numbers -- from previous assignment
    }
    a = a << 1;
    b = b >> 1;
}

return product;
```

I get: Product= 0x000000009a431064 As unsigned= 2588086372

What I should get: Product= 0x000000039A431064 As unsigned= 15472988260

Comment: It can be just overflow. What is the size of `long` on your system? Try `long long`. Also, make sure that `a` and `b` are of the same type as `product`.

Comment: Can you post the examples that fail?

Comment: 1) Confident that `a` is too narrow.  Try `unsigned long long awide = a; while(b != 0){ if((b & 0x01) != 0){ product = BinaryAdd(product, awidth); } awide = awide << 1;  b = b >> 1; }.` 2) Useful to see definition of `BinaryAdd()`.

Comment: Both the/a variable shifted left/multiplied by a power of two (`a`) and `BinaryAdd()` (and at least one of its parameters) need to be as wide as the sum of the factor widths as well as as wide as `product`.